# How to read 3D tensor (nested-lists) which are stored in an Excel column as pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nested-lists

I have a big Excel list with the columns 'x' and 'y'. I want to read the whole list as a pandas DataFrame. The problem which occurs is that all elements of 'x' and 'y' are strings when using the `pd.read_excel()` method.
The datatype of 'x' should be a 3d numpy tensor (volumetric data,) and the datatype of 'y' are only integers (1s and 0s). Transforming 'y' to integers is no problem and works fine with

```
df2.y = df.y.astype(int)
```

but I don't know how to convert the data in 'x' as a numpy array with floats as elements, since every element also has brackets that are read as a string.

Each element of 'x' has the dimensions (100, 100, 100).

I tried something like this:

```
df2['x'] = df2['x'].apply(np.asfarray(df2['x'],float))
```

but it does not work, because the brackets are also loaded as strings, and it cannot convert '[' or ']' into a number.

Comment: This has come up before.  Formats designed to save 2d data - rows and columns, have to use strings to store the '3rd' dimension.  And `str(array)` is designed for display purposes only; recreating an array from it has all kinds of problems, including the [] and ....

Answer (score 0):

as long as the strings in 'x' all follow the same pattern you can replace the not needed 'extras' and split. You can either do:

1) Just use the string replace and split:

```
df2['x'] = df.x.apply(lambda x: np.asfarray(x.replace("[", "").replace("]","").split(",")))
```

2) Use regex for replacing as such:

```
import re
df2['x'] = df.x.apply(lambda x: np.asfarray(re.sub(r"[\[\]]", "", x).split(",")))
```

After you have created the `pd.DataFrame` as needed, I would save it in a format that can handle a lot of types such as `pickle`. For that just use `df2.to_pickle('path/to/file.pkl')` to save and `df2 = pd.read_pickle('path/to/file.pkl')` to load the data back in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, I tried it but unfortunately both methods failed. The error message is something like this: ` ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.\n 0. 0. 0. ...  ` I also tried the pickle method but since the generated df contains more than 1000 rows and in each column 'x' there is a 100x100x100 numpy ndarray, it does not work due to memory problems. Is there any other method that I can export and import a DataFrame without losing the data type ? Thank you